# Variable importance with ranger

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I trained a random forest using `caret` + `ranger`.

```
fit <- train(
    y ~ x1 + x2
    ,data = total_set
    ,method = "ranger"
    ,trControl = trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, allowParallel = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
    ,tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = c(4,5,6))
    ,importance = 'impurity'
)
```

Now I'd like to see the importance of variables. However, none of these work :

```
> importance(fit)
Error in UseMethod("importance") : no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"
> fit$variable.importance
NULL
> fit$importance
NULL

> fit
Random Forest 

217380 samples
    32 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 173904, 173904, 173904, 173904, 173904 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  RMSE        Rsquared 
  4     0.03640464  0.5378731
  5     0.03645528  0.5366478
  6     0.03651451  0.5352838

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 4.
```

Any idea if & how I can get it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`varImp(fit)` will get it for you.

To figure that out, I looked at `names(fit)`, which led me to `names(fit$modelInfo)` - then you'll see `varImp` as one of the options.

Comment: Yeah, I found it too in the meantime by diving into `caret`'s doc. Thank you for that useful method to find information, though ! It turns out `varImp()` is the way to get variable importance for most models trained with caret's `train()`. Note to future users though : I'm not 100% certain and don't have the time to check, but it seems it's necessary to have `importance = 'impurity'` (I guess `importance = 'permutation'` would work too) passed as parameter in `train()` to be able to use `varImp()`.

Comment: Another note : it seems that if you train your model with `ranger` but without `caret`, then `importance(fit)` would be the right way to get variable importance. As above, I think the parameter `importance = 'impurity'` (or 'permutation') needs to be in `train()`

Comment: Strange it's not working for me.   No importance values available... hmmm

Comment: this doesn't work for me. The function exists but it returns no importance values available?

Comment: Just to be clear, the default for `ranger` is to not compute `importance`.  You must explicitly specify `importance = 'impurity'` or `importance = 'permutation'` for any of these methods to work, even if you are using `train`.

Comment: Since it took a lot of searching for me to find this, note that `varImp` will also work for `Rborist` models trained with `caret`.

Answer (score 13):

according to @fmalaussena

```
set.seed(123)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = 'cv', 
                     number = 10,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     savePredictions = TRUE,
                     verboseIter = TRUE)

rfFit <- train(Species ~ ., 
               data = iris, 
               method = "ranger",
               importance = "permutation", #***
               trControl = ctrl,
               verbose = T)
```

You can pass either `"permutation"` or `"impurity"` to argument `importance`.
The description for both value can be found here: https://alexisperrier.com/datascience/2015/08/27/feature-importance-random-forests-gini-accuracy.html

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the link is dead by now. Please consider a replacement link

Answer (score 9):

For 'ranger' package you could call an importance with

```
fit$variable.importance
```

As a side note, you could see the all available outputs for the model using str()

```
str(fit)
```